# Reward vs Award

Tags: word-choice

Can these two verbs be used interchangeably? Or do they imply different meanings?

> "My employer rewarded me a trip to
>   Hawaii."
>
> "My employer awarded me a trip to
>   Hawaii."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct verb to use really depends on the meaning of the corresponding noun.

Award (n): a recognition of a personal achievement, e.g. a scholarship for winning a science fair, a plaque for volunteering 100 hours of community service

Reward (n): compensation or incentive for doing something, e.g. cash for returning a lost wallet, getting to stay up late for tidying one's bedroom

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind adding the correct sample sentences with both `reward` and `award` to the answer?

Comment: It's hard to be certain which verb to use, without knowing the circumstances under which the trip was given. If the employee knew the trip would be given out to the most productive employee, and then became productive in order to receive it, then reward sounds appropriate. But if the employee wasn't expecting it, then award sounds better. I think.

Answer (score 7):

The first sentence should be

> My employer rewarded me with a trip to Hawaii.

The two verbs have a different meaning; *to award* suggests that the giver is in some sense a judge, and that the thing given is deserved (*award a scholarship*).

Comment: Should the second one be `My employer awarded me with a trip to Hawaii.` as well?

Comment: @Hamid: No. It is _he was awarded the Purple Heart_, not _he was awarded with the Purple Heart_.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is more accurate: it depends.

- Was the trip a recognition of a personal achievement? If yes, then it is an award.

or

- Was the trip a compensation or incentive for doing something, e.g. having the highest sales? If yes, then it is a reward.

Seems to me it was a reward, not an award. Usually anything given by an employer is a compensation, for doing something outstanding, for the company.