# "Reward" vs. "award" vs. "prize"

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

Got the following from [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/reward-vs-award) link.

> - Award (n): a recognition of a personal achievement, e.g. a scholarship for winning a science fair, a plaque for volunteering 100 hours of community service
> - Reward (n): compensation or incentive for doing something, e.g. cash for returning a lost wallet, getting to stay up late for tidying one's bedroom.

So, is there anything different for *prize* too? And what about *medal*? How are these words different from each other? Are there any particular reasons a committee might use one word instead of another when naming a particular achievement?

Comment: The information you're asking for can easily be gleaned from and advanced learner's dictionary like the [Macmillan Online](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/prize)

Comment: I've nominated this question for reopening, because I think there's more to this discussion than the dictionary explains. If I was going to create a new honor of some kind, to recognize a particular outstanding achievement, is there any reason I would call it a Medal (like the Caldecott Medal), vs. an Award (like the Turing Award), vs. a Prize (like the Pulitzer Prize). Maybe the O.P. could have done a better job of framing the question by asking about something more specific than _semantic_ differences, but I still think this could be a good question about word usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both etymonline and wiktionary provide useful comparisons of the several words you ask about.  For example, see etymonline's entries for *[reward](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=reward)*,  *[award](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=award)*, *[prize](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=prize)*, *[apprise](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=apprise)*, *[appraise](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=appraise)*, *[price](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=price)*, *[praise](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Praise)*, *etc*.  A note in the *praise* entry comments, “Now a verb in most Germanic languages (Ger. *preis*, Dan. *pris*, etc.), but only in English is it differentiated in form from cognate *price*.”  A note in the *price* entry comments,

> Praise, price, and prize began to diverge in Old French, with praise emerging in Middle English by early 14c. and prize being evident by late 1500s with the rise of the -z- spelling. Having shed the extra Old French and Middle English senses, the word now again has the base sense of the Latin original.

Note that *[prize](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prize)* has two separate etymologies for its different meanings as (1) a [noun](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prize#Etymology_1) meaning “a taking, capture, ... a thing seized, ... booty” or plunder and (2) a [verb](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prize#Etymology_2) meaning  “To consider something highly valuable” or  “To move with a lever; to force up or open; to prise or pry”.  The noun derives via Middle English and Old French from Latin *prendere* (“to take, seize”); the verb from Latin *pretium* (“price, value”), again via Middle English and Old French.